# Vue2 track changes on table to passed for add/update/removed

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I have a table that shows a paginated result of large data. Those data are loaded at once. The client wants to have a Save All functionality where only those data that the user added/modified/deleted will passed down to the API.

The table:
[image]

Is there a way to only get the data that was added/modified/deleted by the user? I am using Vue2 with Veevalidate and my plan at first is to get only those who are dirty (from veevalidate) but there is no way to do that in Veevalidate. I am not sure now how I can achieve this.

General idea can be accepted.

Comment: is not simple but sure, compare original data with a working copy before *passing* to the API

Comment: @LawrenceCherone while this is possible, looping through thousands of data just to get those has been added/modified/deleted can cause performance issue

Comment: eek, then you should not be pulling thousands of data from the API, add propper pagination then your original issue might not be needed

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I want to implement that way, but I am limited to make changes like you mention. In this case I need to adjust on how the specs were specified.